# Maven way to include a runtime dependency when packaging

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have two Maven projects, A and B, where A depends on B at compile time, but at runtime B needs some classes of A.

What I did is:

A's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>B</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>${B.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

B's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>A</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>${A.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When letting Jenkins compile the projects it fails to compile each other as a downstream project because it finds the circular dependency and avoid the infinite build loop.

So, what I thought is a way to add the A's runtime dependency only when packaging B (when Jenkins executes `mvn package`) so that Jenkins does not find the circular dependencies in the `pom.xml` files and configures the downstream compilation.

Is there any way to accomplish this with an existing Maven plugin or other way?

Thank you

Comment: I imagine that moving those classes from A to B isn't an option, is it? That would be the best thing to do, since the circural dependency isn't nice, maven or not

Comment: HI @MarioTrucco,
unfortunately that's not an option in this case :/

Comment: Try [excluding](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) dependencies (`B` from `A` and `A` from `B`) and including both directly.

Comment: `A depends on B at compile time, but at runtime B needs some classes of A` you probably won't find a "proper" way to solve this issue with Maven (maybe a workaround still exists though). Your issue is caused by your class design (A depends on B and B depends on A), as suggested you should aim to move those classes used by both module into a C module on which both will depend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [this Maven plugin](https://github.com/ilpianista/resolver-maven-plugin) for the same reason.

It adds any listed JAR artifact to the WAR file where this plugin is used. JAR dependencies are resolved and added to the WAR file if not artifact with the same version is found.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to define dependencies only inside the `<dependency>` POM section because that's the only configuration used by the [Maven reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

If you fiddle with custom plugins to introduce your own dependency management ideas you will most likely break the reactor. Even if your custom approach works with regular `mvn clean install` it will usually explode when `-T4` or similar option is used to enable multi threaded builds. There is simply no way to explicitly define the module build order in POM as it's governed by the reactor.

The usual way of sharing code between modules is to create a new module `C` which is depended on by both `A` and `B`.